# Axios react node post request is giving a 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am trying to save the desired book to my MongoDB database when I press the saved button I get a 422 error I pass in the data as an object but for some reason, the data doesn't appear in the response back from the server The data is being passed to the Axios call but for some reason, the data property always returns an empty object,

The save handler

```
const handleSave = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let save = books.filter((book) => book.id === event.target.id);
    // console.log(save);
    // const da/ta = ;

    // console.log(data);
    API.saveBook({
      title: save[0].title,
      authors: save[0].author,
      description: save[0].description,
      image: save[0].image,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        alert("book saved");
        console.log(res);
        // console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // console.log(data);
        console.log("book not saved");
        console.log(err.response);
      });
  };
```

This is the book model and the heroku link where you can see what is being logged out

```
const bookSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    authors: [{ type: String, required: true }],
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

[Heroku Link](https://googlebooksf.herokuapp.com/)

[github](https://github.com/jmsn123/googleBooks)

I have console.logs in my inspect so you can check those out to see the response im getting back

Answer (score 1):

I have cloned this repository and tested on both your Heroku link and locally, and cannot recreate the error locally. I suspect something to do with the MongoDB server rather than a code issue. I recommend you test creating a record in the live/Heroku-attached MongoDB server using an alternative method.

Thanks,
Will Walsh

Comment: The issue only occurs on books without a description (`volumeInfo.description`).

Comment: I first noticed and thought that was the issue, but before I commented, I tested further and found that the 422 error occurs even when there is a description, and there is no error returned. I believe the description error we have noticed is caused by Mongoose schema validation prior to a document creation call to the MongoDB server, which would leave my suspicion valid.

Comment: "I tested further and found that the 422 error occurs even when there is a description, and there is no error returned." - Interesting. Do you mind sharing the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UmGXQkH
This is a book with a valid model and it returns a 422 error, but without any error, such as when there is no description, the Mongoose model validation returns details saying there is no description

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't reproduce this issue locally. Did you manage to reproduce it locally as well?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error locally either, other than something regarding Mongoose model validation, such as your noted 'description missing' or one where there was no author. This appears to be a live error only, pointing to the Heroku site being unable to contact the MongoDB server.

Comment: My mongo atlas server is connected I’ll double check my env variables but I checked already

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `volumeInfo.description` is `undefined` for some books. The API returns a 422 error since `description` is required but is not present in the request payload. You could pass a default description if the book doesn't have one.

```
result = {
  // ...
  title: result.volumeInfo.title,
  description: result.volumeInfo.description || "This book doesn't have a description",
  // ...
}
```

Or you could remove the `required` validation for the `description` field if it's not an issue.

---

I would recommend you rename `author` to `authors` in the `result` object for clarity.

```
result = {
  // ...
  authors: result.volumeInfo.authors,
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @JimClayton Can you do a `console.log(err)` in `booksController.create` and add the result to the question?

Comment: I’m gonna add where I’m calling the controller